# Libgdx camera/scaling issue

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, scaling, aspect-ratio

This is just a really quick post wondering what i have done wrong?

I want the background to be filled on the whole screen with whatever screen sizes i have but this does not make it work.  [image: This is the result when i run the program]Here is all the code:

```
// Variables

Jump game;

OrthographicCamera cam;

SpriteBatch sb;

 // Variables

public SplashScreen(Jump game)
{
    this.game = game;

    cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    cam.translate(cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.viewportHeight / 2);

    sb = new SpriteBatch();
}

public void show() 
{

}

public void render(float delta) 
{
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0.2F, 0.6F, 1F, 1F);

    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.update();

    sb.begin();

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    sb.draw(Assets.splash_spr_background, 0, 0);

    sb.end();

}
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your asset is not the same size as the viewport. See the links below. Libgdx uses the Viewport class to handle this.

[How to deal with different aspect ratios in libGDX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198932/how-to-deal-with-different-aspect-ratios-in-libgdx)

[How to scale image according to different screen resolutions in libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399233/how-to-scale-image-according-to-different-screen-resolutions-in-libgdx)

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: I thought that the camera/sb or whatever would notice that the sprite is smaller than the screen size and resize it somehow? xD

Comment: Not automatically. Spritebatch has a draw method that allows you to manually set the width and height if you want to do it by hand, otherwise Viewport for you.

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture-float-float-float-float-

Comment: Okay i will try the viewport thingy and if it works you will get +REP & marked as answer for your help :)

Comment: - I cannot seem to get it to work! Im so frustrated, the background covers the whole screen but i do not see the text as in the image i posted, it's just the background color. This is the code im using:

Comment: public SplashScreen(Jump game)
    {
     this.game = game;
     
     BG_WORLD_WIDTH = 100;
     
     BG_WORLD_HEIGHT = 50;
     
     aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();  
     
     cam = new OrthographicCamera(BG_WORLD_HEIGHT * aspectRatio, BG_WORLD_HEIGHT);
     
     cam.position.set(BG_WORLD_WIDTH / 2, BG_WORLD_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
     
     sb = new SpriteBatch();
     
     Assets.splash_spr_background.setSize(BG_WORLD_WIDTH, BG_WORLD_HEIGHT);
    }

Comment: public void render(float delta) 
 {
  Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0.2F, 0.6F, 1F, 1F);
  
  Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  cam.update();
  
  sb.begin();
  
  sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
  
  sb.draw(Assets.splash_spr_background, 0, 0);
  
  sb.end();
  
 }

Comment: There are errors in your math. If you use a Viewport, you won't need to worry about the math.